# In an Angular *ngFor loop, can I output or render to different / multiple locations in my template?

Tags: html, angular, angular-directive, ngfor, ng-container

I have an array of items, each with a category that is sometimes shared. What I want to do is group the items in my template by their category. Currently I'm achieving this by simply looping the array for each category, but that's inefficient. I want to loop the array once only, and output to the different sections respectively. I can't seem to search a clear way to do this. Here's a rough outline of what I'm hoping to do:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
  <!--
    The checkbox below needs to be output to one of the proceeding
    4 sections based on its category, I assume using a switch.
  -->
  <mat-checkbox
    class="item-toggle"
    [checked]="item.enabled"
    (change)="toggleItem(item)"
    >{{ item.name }}</mat-checkbox
  >
</ng-container>

<h3>Category 1</h3>
<section class="item-choices" #category1></section>

<h3>Category 2</h3>
<section class="item-choices" #category2></section>

<h3>Category 3</h3>
<section class="item-choices" #category3></section>

<h3>Category 4</h3>
<section class="item-choices" #category4></section>
```

Is there a way to do this with the default directives available?

Edit: Updated the example. I wanted to highlight that I do not wish to duplicate the category sections. I wanted to direct the output to the 4 separate locations. I can achieve this now by either running 4 loops, once for each category. Or, in my ts, I can filter the array into subarrays for each category.

I was hoping there would be a way to do this with the template or directives alone.

Comment: You will use something known as ngFor

Comment: @AshutoshKumar thanks, but that's not the question I've asked.

Comment: When it comes to grouping and sorting, Angular and JS have lots of tools to perform the conversions. But you are looking efficiency as I always do. I came to conclusion that lots of data manipulation shouldn't be done on the client, but at your data layer (EF / DB et al). If you have access to this layer, a simpler method might be to perform the grouping there, instead of at the Angular app.

Answer (score 0):

Have the selected items saved in an array, then bind to the selection. So, something like this may work:

`checked` property, where `checked` is an array of either `items` or `indexes` for items.

Then, bind to the section using `ngModel`. In the first instance, you would have the first section be like:

```
<section class="item-choices" [(ngModel)]="checked[0]" #category1></section>
```

and in the second:

```
<section class="item-choices" [(ngModel)]="items[checked[0]]" #category1></section>
```

basically, bind your selected choice to the `ts` and then use the bound property to bind the sections